# Красивое (правильное) определение переменных в языке Python

Tags: python

Какой стиль определения переменных в языке Python на сегодняшний день употребим в сообществе программистов: `myVariable` или `my_variable` ?

Comment: Тот, который опИсан в PEP (Например: https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Базовый Coding Style Guide по Питону изложен в [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Если кратко, то переменные и функции следует называть `my_own_variable`, `my_own_function` (lower-case, underscore-separated) Такой стиль (имхо) является общепринятым Питон-стилем. Допускается использование camelCase (`myVar`, `myFunc`) при условии, что этот стиль превалирует в проекте.